# How to parse json output through shell / Python

Tags: linux, shell, shell-script, python, json

I am running a curl command which gives me json response.
Now I want to parse the response output to get the keys and corresponding values from the output *or* getting value for a particular key.

I need to do this through shell (preferred) or Python. If possible, through the command line.

Comment: Use a tool like [jshon](http://kmkeen.com/jshon/)...

Comment: In Python? Seriously?! First thing you'll find when you search the internet for "python json parser" is [the Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html). Please do at least basic searching before asking questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a job for jq: http://stedolan.github.io/jq/.

Comment: can you give some examples ????